# jScrollPane and jQuery 1.8.0

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

After update to jQuery 1.8.0, jScrollPane gives me this error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   [type=text/javascript],not([type])

in this line:

```
$("script",elem).filter('[type=text/javascript],not([type])').remove();
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure that jscrollpane is compatible with the latest version of jquery

Comment: It should be `$("script",elem).filter('[type="text/javascript"],:not([type])').remove();`

Comment: With jqueryUI 1.9pre and the change by Esailija it works ok @Kyokasuigetsu.

Answer (score 7):

1. `not` is a pseudo selector and should be preceded by a `:` used as `:not()`
2. While filtering by attribute name-value use as `selector[attr="value"]` - `[type="text/javascript"]`.

So it should be -

```
.filter('[type="text/javascript"],:not([type])')
```

Comment: Yes, I think jScrollpane needs to do that

Answer (score 5):

Here is a patch for jScrollPane. Works fine with jquery 1.8.x
https://github.com/jarednorman/jScrollPane/commit/2ef4821afa1dd62db056e3dea737e6f84b17fb13

This is a final minified version:
https://raw.github.com/jarednorman/jScrollPane/2ef4821afa1dd62db056e3dea737e6f84b17fb13/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of [jScrollPane (v2.0.0beta12 - 2012-09-27)](https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/blob/38f2aa9db7fdf5f1247eeeaaacaf8506bb77cdcc/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js) added support for jQuery 1.8:

```
$("script", elem).filter('[type="text/javascript"],:not([type])').remove();
```