# How can I edit jQuery files within WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am facing a similar problem as [jScrollPane and jQuery 1.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903758/jscrollpane-and-jquery-1-8-0) which requires me to edit a javascript file within WordPress. How can I do this from the admin UI ? Or do I need to get a specific plugin for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a plugin that has this js, then yes you have access to the files in the wordpress backend.

1. Just go to Plugins - Editor.
2. And on the right hand side you can select your plugin in the drop down. Select it and press Select button.
3. It should list the plugin files on the right hand side, find the file you want to add and the editor on the left will populate with what ever is in the js file.

Comment: I believe the js comes from the theme. Is there a way to modify it ?

Comment: Yea there is. Go to Appearance - Theme Editor. You should see a list of the theme files on the right hand side. Good luck!